# Count array keys

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => WWW
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Hi
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Hello
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => World
    )

)
```

I have the above array and I want to count the number of keys.

When using the following code

```
$temp = array_keys($array);
echo $temp;
```

the result is 2 instead of 4 (0,1,2,3). What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Just count the array itself: `count($array)`. There's always the same amount of keys as there are values!

Comment: `array_keys` returns an array. So how can the result be '2'??

Comment: The result of `echo $temp;` should be `'Array'`, since `array_keys` returns an *array* of the keys.

Comment: @JosephSilber with the mess of bad answers below, you need to just post yours so we can upvote it =)

Answer (score 4):

You need to count the array in order to get a number:

```
  $arr = array
    (
        "0" => array
        (
            "name" =>"WWW"
        ),

    "1" => array
    (
        "name" => "Hi"
    ),

    "2" => array
    (
        "name" => "Hello"
    ),

    "3" => array
    (
        "name" => "World"
    )

    );

    $keys_count = count($arr);
    echo $keys_count;
```

Answer (score 4):

Just count the array itself: `count($array)`.

There's always the same amount of keys as there are values!

Answer (score -1):

Very simple buddy. Look this:

```
 $array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
 print_r(count($array));
```

**php.net** help you for all!  ;)

Comment: Even simpler `echo count($array);`.  Done.

Comment: Using `array_keys` is unnecessary. So is using `print_r` on an integer.